# I have my HD6450 GPU installed in my pc

Tags: windows, gpu, amd-radeon, amd-graphics-card

When it has no drivers installed, it works fine, except that I can't run games like Minecraft, because they require newer drivers. When I install drivers, my PC screen turns black, but PC boots fine because I can remote connect into it with anydesk. AMD Control Catalyst doesn't recognise my monitor connected to DVI, even tho it was detected prior to driver installation.

What can I do to make it work?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which Catalyst & precisely what OS? Last available for that card would be 15.7.1 going from memory. It's a legacy card so there are no new drivers for it. [Don't use the Crimson beta unless you absolutely have to, it wasn't great]

Comment: Well... I'm currently using Windows 7 Ultimate and I used web setup...

Comment: That's not precise on either front. The devil is in the detail. Win7 SP1 with all updates? 32 or 64? and... what 'web setup' ?

Comment: well. I'm sorry didn't know that details were so importatnt... 

Ok, so I have Windows 7 sp1 with latest updates 64bit

web setup is the one here http://prntscr.com/fqbdpg

Comment: Maybe try this link directly for the 15.7.1 - http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy3&os=Windows%207%20-%2064 -  Run it as a clean install [there's an option in Advanced during the setup]

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry :/